# How to use tf.contrib.rnn.convLSTMCell class in tensorflow

Tags: python-2.7, tensorflow, deep-learning

I would like to use a convolution LSTM in my research but I'm having a difficult time figuring out the exact way to implement this class in tensorflow. Here is what I have so far. I get no errors, but I am seriously doubting my implementation. Can anyone confirm if I am doing this correctly?

```
n_input = 4
x = tf.placeholder(tf.float32,shape=[None,n_input,HEIGHT,WIDTH,2])
y = tf.placeholder(tf.float32,shape=[None,HEIGHT,WIDTH,2])

convLSTM_cell = tf.contrib.rnn.ConvLSTMCell(
    conv_ndims=2,
    input_shape = [HEIGHT,WIDTH,DEPTH],
    output_channels=2,
    kernel_shape=[3,3]
    )

outputs, states = tf.nn.dynamic_rnn(convLSTM_cell, x, dtype=tf.float32)

weights =  tf.Variable(tf.random_normal([3,3,2,2]))
biases = tf.Variable(tf.random_normal([2]))

conv_out = tf.nn.conv2d(outputs[-1],weights,strides=[1,1,1,1],padding='SAME')
out = tf.nn.sigmoid(conv_out + biases)
```

UPDATE:

printing the size of outputs gives the shape=(?,4,436,1024,2) but I think I want (?,5,436,1024,2) or (?,1,436,1024,2).

UPDATE2:

So according to a fellow lab mate, the 4 outputs corresponds to the lstm outputs for each frame and so it is working correctly. Apparently all I have to do is take output #4 and that is the predicted future time frame.

A stackoverflow confirmation would put my mind at ease on this whole thing.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, you are correct!
The output dimension will match the input dimension. If you actually want the `(?,5,436,1024,2)` output, you will have to look at the history, `state.h`. the last four `[-4]` of it will still correspond to the output.